# Optimal way to load multiple instances of the same image

Tags: python, image, kivy, grid-layout

I am messing around with Kivy, and trying to get some game like application with some kind of 2D grid. In my design each cell oh grid should have its own graphical representation, depending on whats inside.
Below is my current simple code which just creates grid and insert some images in each cell.

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self,images,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.images = []
        for img in images:
            self.add_image(img)
        self.bind(pos=self.callback,size=self.callback)
    def add_image(self,image):
        self.images.append(Image(source=image,allow_stretch = True,keep_ratio = False))
        self.add_widget(self.images[-1])
    def callback(self,instance,value):
        for image in instance.images:
            image.pos = instance.pos
            image.size = instance.size

class StartScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(StartScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        i = 10
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=i)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        for i in range(i*i):
            self.layout.add_widget(MyWidget(['./images/grass.png','./images/bug1.png']))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return StartScreen()
```

The problem is that while all images are the same, thay are loaded into memory again for each cell, from what I can see. It is not efficient, especially when there will be 10000 cells or so.
I have tried to add the same image to each cell, but it turns out that each widget can have only one parent.
I also have tried to initialize new images with texture of one already initialized, but that bringed no improve.
I tried to get texture of loaded image, and then create rectangle with it as a texture. Something like this:

```
def add_image(self,texture):
    with self.canvas:
        rect = Rectangle(texture=texture,pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.rects.append(rect)
```

where texture is:

```
Image(source='./images/grass.png',allow_stretch = True,keep_ratio = False).texture
```

It have improved memory usage (from 430MB to 160MB for 10000 cells with 200kB images. But still, this is quite much for two images. :)

My question: is there more efficient way of creating 2D grid with a lot of repeating images, in Kivy?
Maybe my approach to the problem is flawed - I have really no expirence in creating games...

Comment: I am not completely sure but you might want to try an [`Atlas`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html). It is meant to reduce the amount of calls to the server or hard drive by loading one image instead of 2 in your case. However, I am tempted to think that there might be some memory management too. Not completely sure but it worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory issue you see is from your widgets not from mismanagement of textures, Image textures in kivy are cached using kivy's internal [cache](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.cache.html) mechanism so if you try and load a image 100 times in one minute kivy will just re-use the existing texture from cache.

This cache does timeout after a set time though and would be re-loaded from disk after this timeout. [Image](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image) widget for this reason has a [reload](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.reload) method and a [nocache](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.nocache) property that can be set. You can set the cache manually ::

```
from kivy.cache import Cache
Cache._categories['kv.image']['limit'] = 0
Cache._categories['kv.texture']['limit'] = 0
```

For games though one should always try and use [Atlas](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html), it's cache doesn't timeout, the whole mechanism is geared towards allowing you better performance and texture management. Other advantages include one single texture to be uploaded to the gpu = huge improvement in upload time, read from disk time is reduced considerably.

Every widget no matter how trivial has overhead and when dealing with 10,000+ iterations of the same Widget. You are bound to get memory usage issues. Widgets aren't suitable for such a usage. You should look at using repeating textures,
manipulating texture coordinates, drawing straight onto the canvas without using widgets. Something like (untested)::

```
texture = Image('grid.jpg').texture
texture.wrap = 'repeat'
texture.uvsize = (20, 20)
with self.canvas:
    Color(1, 1, 1)
    Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(2000, 2000), texture=texture)
```

You might want to look at [KivEnt](https://github.com/Kovak/KivEnt/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorials) and cymunk as physics engines if you are interested in writing games.